# Renaming a Domain Controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-controller, rename

how can i rename a domain controller in windows server 2003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full instructions are [here](http://www.petri.co.il/windows_2003_domain_controller_rename.htm) but the gist is that run this in CMD

> C:\WINDOWS>netdom computername olddomain.com /add:newdomain.com

then enter

> C:\WINDOWS>netdom computername olddomain.com /makeprimary:newdomain.com

reboot then

> C:\WINDOWS>netdom computername NEWdomain.com /remove:OLDdomain.com

Though I highly recommend you install from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [answer](http://www.petri.co.il/windows_2003_domain_controller_rename.htm).

> Although not the best idea in the world and although I rather re-build the entire server from scratch, this can be done in Windows Server 2003-based Domain Controllers. The procedure is quite simple. It only requires one reboot of the DC that had it's name renamed. You don't even have to sit near the DC, you can accomplish it from any computer that has the Windows Server 2003 Support Tools installed, and if you have the appropriate user credentials.
>
> **Note:** Only Windows Server 2003 Domain Controllers can be renamed.
>
> **Note:** You must be a member of the Domain Admins group.
>
> Another Note: Domain Controllers running Microsoft's Certificate Authority services (CA) can never be renamed.
>
> **Lamer Note:** This is NOT the same as renaming your entire domain! In order to do that read [Windows 2003 Domain Rename Tool](http://www.petri.co.il/windows_2003_domain_rename.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by **netdom** tool. It is available by default in Windows Server 2008 and later version but it is not available by default in **Windows Server 2003**, Netdom.exe is part of the **Windows Server 2003 Support Tools**.

You can download them by the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326

Note: You need to restart the server after you install the Support Tools.

Then you can do the following steps 
1. Run the command: netdom computername  /add:
2. Run the command: netdom computername  /makeprimary:
3. Restart the computer.
4. Run the command: netdom computername  /remove:

You can refer this article for clear information http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/08/how-to-rename-domain-controller-name.html

Comment: This answer has already been supplied. Multiple times, actually.